# How do I plot multiple lines (by levels of factor) for year series?

Tags: r, plot

I'm fairly new to R and I've been having trouble with a plot.

I'm trying to create a line plot with:
$YEAR on the X axis
$METRIC on the Y axis
a different-colored line for each country (meaning, a total of 3 lines on the same plot)

$COUNTRY is a factor with 3 levels

```html
COUNTRY YEAR    METRIC
USA     2000    14.874
USA     2001    15.492
USA     2002    13.091
USA     2003    14.717
CAN     1999    15.031
CAN     2000    14.343
CAN     2001    12.972
CAN     2002    13.216
SWE     1999    14.771
SWE     2000    17.033
SWE     2001    15.932
SWE     2002    14.516
SWE     2003    15.655
```

When I create the plot with

> plot(df$YEAR, df$METRIC, col=df$COUNTRY, type="p")

I get a plot with points for each (x,y) combination and different color for each level of the factor $COUNTRY

However, when I try to get a line for each country, with

> plot(df$YEAR, df$METRIC, col=df$COUNTRY, type="l")

I get one non-stopping line, that starts with the 4 observations of "USA" and then goes back to the first year of the next country ("CAN").

[image: screenshot attached]

**Can anyone explain why is this happening?
Is it possible to create this plot using only the pre-built functions?**

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Comment: base R `plot` doesn't work like `ggplot2`: to say `col=df$COUNTRY` does not mean it is going to group the lines, separating the endpoints, and apply colors intuitively. I think your immediate options (1) make a single base plot, then add each country's data as an individual call to `lines`; (2) use `segments` and place `NA`s between each country (fragile and too much work, typically); or (3) switch to `ggplot2` or `lattice` where grouping/faceting like what you want is a bit more natural.

Comment: Something like `library(ggplot2); ggplot(df) + geom_line(aes(YEAR, METRIC, color=COUNTRY))` is more likely what you're looking for, and is relatively easy to read once you start migrating your thought-process from base-R to grammar-of-graphics.

Comment: If you stay with base-R, realize that `lines` (and therefore `plot(..., type=";")`) will only use the first color unless `type="h"` (which is not what you are trying to do here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than my comments above, here is a basic `base` implementation. If initially your `$COUNTRY` is a factor (`is.factor(df$COUNTRY)`), then you can skip the creation of `ctryfctr` and change the lines call to `lines(..., col=x$COUNTRY[1])`:

```
df$ctryfctr <- factor(df$COUNTRY)
plot(NA, xlim=range(df$YEAR), ylim=range(df$METRIC))
for (x in split(df, df$COUNTRY)) lines(x$YEAR, x$METRIC, col=x$ctryfctr[1])
```

[image: sample per-country plot]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to mix up some concepts, I thought it would be helpful to clarify things a bit.

R's base plot package is great for quick sketching without prior knowledge, but more complicated plots are defined easier with ggplot2 package. You can install it with `install.packages("ggplot2")`. With ggplot2 you can group the lines as you already tried, and as r2evans already pointed out.

`library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df) + geom_line(aes(YEAR, METRIC, group=COUNTRY, color=COUNTRY))`

So, you tell the ggplot that you are using the df as your data. You define the x and y axis for `geom_line` inside `aes()`. With `group=` you define the grouping variable, and with `color=` you define that each line is using a different color.

Hope that you have great time with R and ggplot2!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I really appreciate it!